# Using lodash, why is the map method within flow not working?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a users object am trying to use the lodash `map()` method on it to have it return only the userIds, while filtering out any users with the `currentUserId`. I wanted to avoid using `chain()` since it pulls in the entire library, so it seemed that the `flow()` method is perfect, yet it's not mapping to an array of Id's.

```
import {
  map, filter, flow,
} from 'lodash';

const users = {
    123: {
      uid: 123
    },
    456: {
      uid: 456
    }
};

const currentUserId = 123;

const userIds = flow(
  map(user => user.uid),
  filter(userId => userId !== currentUserId),
)(users);
```

Unfortunately, this is returning the same object as was passed into it. How can I get an array with the ids of all the users that are not the current user?

Comment: `_.map(user => user.uid)` is evaluated *before* `_.flow()` is even called.

Comment: @Pointy This seems like the functional usage of lodash, so shouldn't `_.map` be the curried invocation that creates a new function that expects an object to execute the mapping against? Unless OP is not using the lodash in its functional form, then the `_.map` shouldn't executing right after

Comment: Lodash does not (and cannot) change the way basic JavaScript expression evaluation works. The Lodash `_.flow()` method expects to be passed an array of function references. That's not what's being done in the posted code.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not following you. Do you mind providing an answer with the code written correctly?

Comment: `_.map(user => user.uid)` is a **function call**, not a function.

Comment: @Pointy *it returns a function*. Specifically it's a curried version of `map(callback, target)` so the returned function is (effectively) `target => target.map(callback)`

Comment: [Here's the documentation for `_.map()`.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map).  It iterates over the collection and returns a new array. Click on the little `src` button on the documentation page and read the source code. It does not return a function. The `_.flow()` method *does* return a function, one that's a composition of the functions in the array passed into  it. The code in the post here is *not* passing an array of functions to `_.flow()`.

Comment: @Pointy Then explain [the FP variant of lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) and why does it appear to work [exactly as I described](http://jsbin.com/wexadif/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: @vlaz well fine, *if* the OP had mentioned that variant at all in the actual question I'd agree. *edit* also thanks for pointing that out; I'm not a Lodash user (usually) but I would definitely prefer that architecture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer applies for the standard version of lodash. Please see @Vlaz's answer for a look at the functional programming version of lodash.

---

When you write `_.map(user => user.uid)` it is actually invoking the function at that time. What you're really attempting to do is to create function that is similar to `_.map`, but has one of its arguments already set.

Fortunately, Lodash has a built-in to handle this situation - `_.partialRight`

```
const userIds = _.flow(
  _.partialRight(_.map, user => user.uid)
  _.partialRight(_.filter, userId => userId !== currentUserId),
)(users);
```

[Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#partialRight)

---

Alternatively if you wish to use plain JS rather than importing a new function, you can simply wrap it in an anonymous function to pass the arguments properly.

```
const userIds = _.flow(
  (users) => _.map(users, user => user.uid),
  (users) => _.filter(users, userId => userId !== currentUserId),
)(users);
```

Comment: `When you write _.map(user => user.uid) it is actually invoking the function at that time.` [Here is how `_.map` doesn't invoke the function](http://jsbin.com/wexadif/1/edit?html,js,console).

Comment: @vlaz If the OP was using the FP version of lodash, I would expect them to have written `import { map, filter, flow } from 'lodash/fp';`. I was unaware of that variant, but if they were using that library then you are correct. I will update my answer to state that it is for the standard version of lodash

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you are not using the [functional version of lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide).

```js
var users = {
    123: {
      uid: 123
    },
    456: {
      uid: 456
    }
};
var currentUserId = 123;

const userIds = _.flow(
  _.map(user => user.uid),
  _.filter(userId => userId !== currentUserId)
)(users);

console.log("result with normal lodash", userIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var users = {
    123: {
      uid: 123
    },
    456: {
      uid: 456
    }
};
var currentUserId = 123;

const userIds = _.flow(
  _.map(user => user.uid),
  _.filter(userId => userId !== currentUserId)
)(users);

console.log("result with lodash FP", userIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

As per the Lodash FP guide, you should be importing that into your files

```
// Load the fp build.
var fp = require('lodash/fp');
```

In your case, you can just import just `map`, `filter`, and `flow` but you should get their lodash FP variants.

Comment: OMG! I wasn't even aware of the functional version of Lodash! This is so freaking helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @Fogmeister it's awesome, I agree. You *can* manually convert functions from "normal" to FP, if you want/need. You have to pass them through `flip`/`rearg` -> `curry` and I think you might need explicitly set `ary` for some (most?) otherwise the curry doesn't know the arity with optional parameters. You can `flow` all these together. It's not ideal, as you need to convert each function you want to use and you might as well use lodash/fp, however it *might* be of limited use if you are stuck with "normal" lodash and need functional approach in some section.

Comment: Currently I was doing all the fp stuff myself with `partial` and `partialRight` everywhere. For now the best bit is that I can remove all of those that I was using and just use the fp function instead. :D

Answer (score 3):

Can do this with a simple native JS reduce of array created by `Object#values()` with no more code than using lodash

```js
const users = {123: {uid: 123},456: {uid: 456}};

const currId = 123;


const userIds = Object.values(users)
            .reduce((a, {uid}) => uid !== currId ? a.concat(uid): a, [])
    

console.log(userIds)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```